# How to convert NumPy array to cv array without using fromarray()?

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x, numpy

I am using opencv 3.0 beta and Python 3.4 and I am new to image processing with Python. I have used C++ before for computer vision and image processing works.

I tried to convert a NumPy array to a cv matrix:

```
mapping = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta), centre[0]],
                   [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta), centre[1]]])
map_matrix_cv = cv.fromarray(mapping)
```

But I can't use that code fragment because it uses the cv namespace. I am using cv2 and there is no `fromarray()` method in cv2.

Can anyone help?

Comment: please use cv2, not the deprecated cv api. and in cv2, images *are* numpy arrays already, so no conversion required.

Comment: OpenCV is based on `Numpy` data structure, so you don't need to convert it. Just use it as your cv matrix. And final point as @berak said use new versions of OCV :)

Comment: weird, there shouldn't be cv (or cv2.cv) anymore in opencv3.0 . are you sure, you don't have an old version around ?